# Translate track 2 data using key wrapped under LMK

Tags: iso8583, jpos

We are using [jPOS](http://jpos.org/) to communicate with the bank for card payment processsing. We recently purchased HSM (Hardware Security Module) for secure key storage. Since this hardware is expensive we are using JCESecurityModule to mimic the actual HSM.

I have ***TMK wrapped under LMK*** and ***clear track 2*** data. I would like to perform the following:

1. un-wrap the TMK under LMK to get the clear TMK value
2. Using the clear TMK value, I would like to encrypt the track 2 data

I am not able to figure out the code to perform the above steps. Could somebody help with sample codes or directions to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your TMK under HSM's LMK into a key known by jPOS.

Then you need to import your foreign key into a key encrypted under jPOS' LMKs.

The jPOS SM Console (call `bin/q2 --cli` and type `help`) can help.